# Prevent eclipse project builder from running twice

Tags: eclipse

In my project I'm using a custom builder (configured under *project properties* / *Builders*) to run a beautifier each time I change an HTML file.

Unfortunately if the beautifier changes the file, the build starts again. And then the beautifier runs the second time, but this time without changing anything. Is there an option to prevent the builder to run in that case?

I would use a *Save Action* with the beautifier, but I can't find such an option for HTML files either.

Comment: In _Project > Properties: Builders_ move your custom builder to the top and make sure it does not touch a file when nothing has to be done.

Comment: Ahem - I said _if the beautifier changes the file_, so there is something been done. But I don't want to prettify again in that case (because even determining that nothing has to be done takes some time).

Comment: Avoid also rewriting or touching of the file even without changing it (you can touch a file without changing it by keeping its content and only updating the modification time stamp of the file). Not only changing a file, but also touching a file by a subsequent project builder triggers a new round of project building.

Comment: I think you still didn't get the point of my post: If I beautify an "uglified" file, I need to change / touch it. The thing is, I don't want to beautify twice in that case, because the second round is unnecessary and doubles the auto build time. The question is not about endless build loops, I'm totally aware of the reasons for such scenarios.

Comment: _"Ahem - I said..."_, _"I think you still didn't get the point of my post..."_ - Sigh. Look, it's stupid simple: your custom project builder has to be on top and(!) it must not touch a file if no changes have to be done (touching != changing). Otherwise, the other project builders are triggered two or more times when saving a single file. Please improve your question. Already after my first comment, the expected reply would have been to show what you have in _Project > Properties: Builders_ to know the order of the project builders. A _Save Action_ can be implemented as an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: I think we talk past each other. And even if I think my question is quite clear (it's the one with the question mark), I'll try to rephrase it: I'm not interested in all the other project builders, was never talking about them - just let's assume, it is the only one. I was asking, how I can prevent _my builder_ from running a second time, after it _had to_ change a file, because it was "ugly". If the answer is "there isn't such an option, but you could write a Save Action as plugin" so be it. In that case an appropriate extension point would be nice because I struggle to find one for HTML.

Comment: Be aware of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Regarding your asked question: When a subsequent project builder changes or touches a project file that does not have the derived attribute and is not in a folder that has the derived attribute, the previous project builders are retriggered. So the order of the project builders matters and which project builder touches which non-derived project file (see my first and second comment; but the other project builders might be relevant too).